# RabbitMQ Container Configurations Error error:badarg

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, lager

I am running Rabbitmq from Docker image. this is the Dockerfile

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_mqtt rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s rabbitmq_stomp rabbitmq_management 

COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
COPY rabbit_init.sh /rabbit_init.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/rabbit_init.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf"]
CMD ["/rabbit_init.sh"]
```

rabbit_init.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

( sleep 12 ; \

echo "Add VirtualHost ..."; \
rabbitmqctl add_vhost EVhost; \

echo "Enable ha-mode for queue mirroring ..."; \`
rabbitmqctl set_policy -p / ha-all ".*" '{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'  --priority 1; \
rabbitmqctl set_policy -p EVhost ha-all ".*" '{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'  --priority 1; \

echo "Creating RabbitMQ user '$RABBITMQ_USER' ...";\
rabbitmqctl add_user $RABBITMQ_USER $RABBITMQ_PASSWORD; \
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags $RABBITMQ_USER administrator; \
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / $RABBITMQ_USER  ".*" ".*" ".*" ; \
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p EVhost $RABBITMQ_USER  ".*" ".*" ".*" ; \

echo "Delete rabbitMq guest user ..."; \
rabbitmqctl delete_user guest; \

)&

rabbitmq-server $@
```

I've these configurations in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

```
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend  = rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s
cluster_formation.k8s.host = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
cluster_formation.k8s.address_type = ip
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.interval = 30
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.only_log_warning = false
cluster_partition_handling = autoheal
queue_master_locator=min-masters
loopback_users.guest = false

log.file = rabbitmq.log
log.dir = /var/log/rabbitmq
log.file.level = debug
log.file.rotation.date = $D0
```

I got this error when running new container

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
    rabbit:start_it/1 line 484
    rabbit:boot_error/2 line 972
    rabbit_lager:log_locations/0 line 97
    rabbit_lager:ensure_lager_configured/0 line 198
    rabbit_lager:lager_configured/0 line 206
    lager:list_all_sinks/0 line 341
    lager_config:get/2 line 71
    ets:lookup(lager_config, {'_global',handlers})
error:badarg
Log file(s) (may contain more information):

{"init terminating in do_boot",badarg}
init terminating in do_boot (badarg)

Crash dump is being written to: /var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump...done
```

**I can't put my hands on the root cause!**

container's filesystem doesn't contain any logs

even the suggested log file `/var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump` is not exist !!

#### my local environment:

Windows 10

docker for desktop

-

Your kind help is very appreciated :)

Comment: Where is `rabbit_init.sh`

Comment: rabbit_init.sh content added to the question.

Comment: @AhmedMetwally me too facing same problem...if you find sol could you help me by posting answer here.